# Cannot deploy with npm run Deploy in React on github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, webpack, github-pages

unfortunately I cannot deploy on GitHub my Color-recognition App in React JS on GitHub pages. I am using Webpack as bundler.

```
My system configuration is: 
Webpack
Environment:
OS: Windows 10
Node: 8.12.0
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 6.4.1
Watchman: Not Found
Xcode: N/A
Android Studio: Not Found
Packages: (wanted => installed)
react: ^16.5.2 => 16.5.2
react-dom: ^16.5.2 => 16.5.2
react-scripts: 1.1.5 => 1.1.5
```

I use extra added dependencies of Clarifai and Gsap and used the following steps:

1. I created on my Github account the repository Color-recognition without md file, and within added gh-pages branch, and in setting of repository under Source added gh-pages branch.
2. git add .
3. git commit -m "Uploading files"
4. git push -f origin master:gh-pages
5. git remote add origin
   https://github.com/Geeeva/Color-recognition.git npm run deploy

The page should be deployed but it couldn't, with the error below. I wanted to put the project demo that is visible.
Tried the same procedure with the master branch of the Color-recognition, and I got the same error.

The error is following:

```
Cannot read property 'email' of null
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! color-recognition-depl@0.1.0 deploy: gh-pages -d build
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the color-recognition-depl@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Ivana\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-09-19T19_58_34_ 829Z-debug.log
```

Link to my Github repo is: https://github.com/Geeeva/Color-recognition

Comment: i have deployed it succesfully using your codebase
here is the link for app:-https://shivasai09.github.io/color/
and link for repo:- https://github.com/shivasai09/color/blob/master/public/index.html#L28

Comment: You did all the same steps I stated above with no error?

Comment: no, i have cloned your repo and changed the url to my git repo and then i force pushed the code to master and after that i have created a branch named gh-pages by taking master as base, in the github UI and made sure that gh-pages branch is  used in the settings  and then ran the code npm run deploy..

Comment: also changed the package.json,  please see my repo

Comment: what changes have you done in package.json, i cannot spot it?

Comment: i have just shifted the position of 'homepage'

Comment: I solved the problem by adding a collaborator from my another account(I created it with aim of testing this problem) then by executing npm run deploy from account for testing and after that everything was fine.  I could thereafter execute npm run deploy directly from Geeeva account, not from collaborator account. I had this problem on all my repositories on Geeeva account.

Answer (score 0):

> I managed to fix it by setting my git config user name and email. (As
>   the link provided above specifies the need of **both**).
>
> So just write in the terminal:
>
> git config --global user.name your name
>
> git config --global user.email @youremail

source:  https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/9hlin1/unable_to_deploy_react_app_to_github_pages/